# How to convert .pcap to .las file

Tags: velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am a complete freshman on Linux, ROS and velodyne so, Please help me with this. I want to process the velodyne data to create an point cloud. As velodyne give output in .pcap file  want to convert it into .las file. So that i can use it for point cloud generation. I have a raw .pcap file that i want to convert..

I tried with converting pcap to txt with tshark it convrt successfully. Then tried to convert txt to las using txt2las command but it give me error.

```
Error:
WARNING: cannot parse '    Urgent pointer: 0
' with 'xyz'. skipping ...
WARNING: cannot parse '    [SEQ/ACK analysis]
' with 'xyz'. skipping ...
WARNING: cannot parse '        [This is an ACK to the segment in frame: 361]
' with 'xyz'. skipping ...
WARNING: cannot parse '        [The RTT to ACK the segment was: 48.340006000 seconds]
' with 'xyz'. skipping ...
WARNING: cannot parse '        [Bytes in flight: 5]
' with 'xyz'. skipping ...
WARNING: cannot parse 'MSN Messenger Service
' with 'xyz'. skipping ...
WARNING: cannot parse '    OUT\r\n
' with 'xyz'. skipping ...
WARNING: cannot parse '
' with 'xyz'. skipping ...
ERROR: could not parse any lines with 'xyz'
```

Can any one Plz Help me with this ????
Thank you :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245094/how-to-convert-.pcap-to-.las-file/) by [Nikka](https://answers.ros.org/users/28163/nikka/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-10-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-10-09**:
I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish with this.

**Comment by [Nikka](https://answers.ros.org/users/28163/nikka/) on 2016-10-15**:
velodyne gives the output in pcap format. But for point cloud software like ArcGIS does not support pcap file format.So i want to convert this pcap file captured from velodyne and convert it into LAS. so that i can process it and get point cloud ..

**Comment by [Kranti](https://answers.ros.org/users/38373/kranti/) on 2018-11-05**:
Hi Nikka,

I am looking for similar solution as you are. Did you got any solution around it?
If yes, can you please share the idea and further information.

warm regards,
Kranti

**Comment by [Nikka](https://answers.ros.org/users/28163/nikka/) on 2018-11-19**:
You have to convert your pcap data to .plc format then using cloud compare you can convert it into las format

**Comment by [Kranti](https://answers.ros.org/users/38373/kranti/) on 2018-11-23**:
Hi Nikka,

Can you guide me how you are converting pcap to .plc. Do you have any sample program?

Regards,
Kranti

**Comment by [Nikka](https://answers.ros.org/users/28163/nikka/) on 2018-11-29**:
Please go through this https://github.com/erik-nelson/blam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not really a ROS question. If you just want to convert the PCAP to use other tools, ROS is neither required nor recommended.

If you do want to view the point cloud using ROS tools, try `rviz`, like the example in this tutorial:

- http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne/Tutorials/Getting%20Started%20with%20the%20HDL-32E

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2016-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0